# DOMDocument::loadHTML why returning 1

Tags: php, domdocument

```
$tag    = <some html tag>;
$a  = new DOMDocument();
$a->loadHTML($tag);
```

im newly using DOMDocument php i have read the documentation but still didn't understand why loadHTML() returning 1, can someone explain it to me?? Thank you in advance

Comment: It's not returning `1`, it's returning `true`. But if you echo that, it prints `1`. See the linked question for how to print `true` or `false` instead.

Comment: What were you expecting it to return instead?